# ¿ Como cerrar sesión en WooCopmmerce sin confirmar?

Tags: php, wordpress, login, woocommerce, log

Queremos que los usuarios de una web cierren sesion sin necesidad de confirmarlo.

Actualmente cuando pulsamos el botón de "Cerrar Sesión", el usuario es dirigido ala la URL http://miSiTioWeb.com/my-account/customer-logout/
y debemos pulsar "Confirmar y Salir"

Bien, queremos evitar este paso y que se cierre sesión automáticamente cuando el usuario pulsa el Botón de Cerrar la Sesión

Hay algún complemento que podía hacer esto, pero preferimos usar funciones.
Hemos probado cosas, pero no conseguimos hacer lo correcto para conseguirlo

```
add_action('wp_logout','ps_redirect_after_logout');
function ps_redirect_after_logout(){
         wp_redirect( 'https://miPaginaFavorita.com' );
         exit();
}
```

Otra opción que hemos manejado es la siguiente, pero tampoco funciona

```
add_action('check_admin_referer', 'logout_without_confirm', 10, 2);

   function logout_without_confirm($action, $result)

      {

      /**

      * Allow log out without confirmation

      */

      if ($action == "log-out" && !isset($_GET['_wpnonce'])) {

      $redirect_to = isset($_REQUEST['redirect_to']) ?
 function logout_without_confirm($action, $result)

      {

      /**

      * Allow log out without confirmation

      */

      if ($action == "log-out" && !isset($_GET['_wpnonce'])) {

      $redirect_to = isset($_REQUEST['redirect_to']) ?

      $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] : '';

      $location = str_replace('&amp;', '&', wp_logout_url($redirect_to));;

      header("Location: $location");

      die();

    }}
```

¿ Como modificar mi función para conseguir  evitar confirmar al cerrar sesión ?
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar a crear el enlace usando wp_logout_url();

Entonces puedes crear una función como esta.

```
function mi_custom_logout(){
    return wp_logout_url( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) );
}
```

Luego solo poner esa función en el botón o link que quieras usar.

Pero si tienes un botón con alguna clase, tipo wc-logout o parecido puedes crear una función js que detecte cuando se hace click en ese botón, eliminar el evento por defecto y activas la url que te creo la función anterior, algo como esto.

```
function logout_button(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( '.nav-brand' ).click(function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            window.location.href = "<?php echo rawurldecode( htmlspecialchars_decode( mi_custom_logout() ) ); ?>";
        });
    </script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'logout_button' );
```

Comment: Gracias por tu interes.
Probe tu ejemplo, pero tampoco funciona. Seguire buscando como corregirlo

Comment: Como lo probaste, esta funcion tambien la probe y va de maravillas.

Comment: Pues añadiendo tu función tal cual a mi archivo function. Mi compañero esta fuera e hice yo la prueba, no se si estara bien echo asi